# Are any of the quests in Fallout 4 time sensitive?

Tags: fallout-4

Are any of the quests in Fallout 4 time sensitive?  Will you fail the Quest if it's not completed in a set amount of time?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two types of quests that I found to be time-sensitive:

- defense of settlements
- freeing hostages (as part of Minuteman quests)

I ignored those for a while and got a notification later that the quests failed.

Comment: I had a friend raging over mic when he realised he failed a mission and needed to revert his save 5+ hours. I believe any mission that asks you to follow someone is time sensitive in a sense, as it appears this NPC he was suppose to follow got killed on his own.

Comment: @Timelord64 that's not time sensitivity per se, but just chance. There's always a chance that people traveling the wasteland will get attacked by for example supermutants or raiders. Same can happen with trade caravans between settlements.

Comment: "Secure new settlement" mission also can be failed that way.

Answer (score 1):

I just failed a main quest , out of nowhere. only explanation I can find is that I waited for about a whole in-game year.

Answer (score -1):

Just failed a mission because I engaged conversation but didn't follow up right away. It was a 2nd kidnapped person in Country Crossing settlement. I goT a failed quest notification after roughly 4 or 5 hrs of dicking around.